# Cannot set certain type values via IL Emit on Object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

I'm creating a function using ILGenerator and Emit to set the value of a property on a specified instance. The main reasons for this being the performance aspects to the solution I'm working on. I have a basic form of code which should take 2 objects and load them via IL to invoke a set function. The problem I am finding is the value I'm passing to be set seems to be ignored and another seemingly generated value is set in its place.

This is the basic usage example made in LinqPad I have created to demonstrate this problem:

```
void Main()
{
    var instance = new TestClass
    {
        Id = new Guid("f0564ce7-f249-4105-8fc4-2c65cfe095f6"),
        StringValue = "Something",
        IntValue = 0
    };

    MethodOne(instance);
}

private void MethodOne(TestClass instance)
{
    var setStringMethod = GenerateMethodAssignment("StringValue");
    setStringMethod(instance, "Something Else");

    var setGuidMethod = GenerateMethodAssignment("Id");
    setGuidMethod(instance, new Guid("f8b0fae2-40bb-422a-815f-2300cceb4329"));

    var setIntMethod = GenerateMethodAssignment("IntValue");
    setIntMethod(instance, 100);
    instance.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class TestClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
}

private Action<object, object> GenerateMethodAssignment(string propName)
{
    var setMethod = typeof(TestClass).GetProperty(propName).GetSetMethod();
    var argTypes = new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) };
    var method = new DynamicMethod(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), null, argTypes, GetType(), true);

    var ilGenerator = method.GetILGenerator();
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, setMethod);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    var action = (Action<object, object>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object, object>));
    return action;
}
```

Output: 
[image: Value set on object]

The string value is set fine but a Guid or Integer value is not set as I would expect. I am fairly new to IL and may be having too high expectations here for the code to be this simple.

However even so I noticed running this code multiple times seems to generate the values for `IntValue` and `Id` in a seemingly sequential order so I curious where exactly these values are coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method and delegate you are creating is taking arguments that are of type object.  That works okay for the target instance (since it is a reference type) and okay for the value argument when it is a string, but not okay when it is a value type like int or guid.  You'll have to add an unbox instruction to convert the boxed value type into the actual value on the stack.

```
 Type propertyType = ...;
 var ilGenerator = method.GetILGenerator();
 ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
 ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
 if (propertyType.IsValueType)
     ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox, propertyType);
 ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, setMethod);
 ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: Of course! Didn't cross my mind, took it for granted. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason I had to use `OpCodes.Unbox_Any` instead of `OpCodes.Unbox`. I have not been able to figure it out exactly from the documentation, but it looks like `Unbox_Any` performs an additional operation that `Unbox` does not.